# In a Django project with different versions of settings.py, can I use a dict.update() method on a setting?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a project with multiple settings files, similar to https://medium.com/@ayarshabeer/django-best-practice-settings-file-for-multiple-environments-6d71c6966ee2. There is a `settings` directory with multiple settings files:

```
settings
├── base.py
├── development.py
├── production.py
└── staging.py
```

The `base.py` contains the default permissions setting for the Django REST framework:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

In production, I would like to use the default JSON renderer instead of the browsable API. So in `production.py` I have something like this:

```
from .base import *

REST_FRAMEWORK.update({
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'
    )
})
```

I find this more DRY than defining a `REST_FRAMEWORK` setting in every file. The question is: will this work? Can you `update` an imported setting dictionary in a `settings.py`?

Comment: yes `settings.py` is read top-down just like any python script, importing the settings from base would mean that REST_FRAMEWORK would already exist and there would be no issue updating the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can update it directly it but **don't** do that. Since dictionaries are mutable, you would be updating the original dictionary, so you would no longer have different settings for the different files. Use `deepcopy` first instead:

```
from .base import *
from copy import deepcopy

REST_FRAMEWORK = deepcopy(REST_FRAMEWORK)
REST_FRAMEWORK.update({
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'
    )
})
```

I've bitten by this in the past, that's why I know. :)